# Как очистить файл используя файловые потоки ввода вывода не закрывая его?

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

Хочу открыть файл записать в него строку, потом, не закрывая файл, начать запись заново, так чтобы старая информация удалилась:

```
std::ofstream file;
file.open("file.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
file << "AA";
file.seekp(std::ios::beg);
file << "1";
file.close();
```

В результате получаю `1A` а должно быть `1`

Comment: [Вроде](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24189274/5812238) нельзя не закрывая файл

Comment: Если б было можно добраться до дескриптора файла, то может, мог бы спасти (нестандартный) `chsize()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартными средствами - никак.

Нестандартно - нужно получить файловый объект `basic_filebuf` с помощью `rdbuf()`, и в нем в конкретной реализации докапываться до файлового объекта - например, в VC++ - это закрытый член `FILE* _Myfile`. Если всяческими грязными хаками :) добраться до него, то можно вызвать `chsize(fileno(_Myfile))`... Но! это **ОЧЕНЬ чревато неприятностями** - как минимум работой через голову самого `basic_filebuf`, который, не подозревая о внесенных изменениях в состояние, может выдать совершенно неожиданное поведение.

Да и не стоит эта овчинка выделки. Зная, где должен заканчиваться файл - откройте новый и перепишите в него только нужное. Будет и надежнее, и проще...